# How should I proceed after black screen during Ubuntu upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, 19.04, 19.10

Started upgrading from 19.04 to 19.10 and left it to run, came back to a blank screen after 5 mins. Unsure if this is normal but it has been 30 mins now and I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Temporary Fix**
To get the system to boot:

1. After turning on your PC, hold the right SHIFT key to get to the GRUB bootloader.
2. Once GRUB is open, press the “e” key to edit the first highlighted entry “Ubuntu”.
3. Move your cursor down to the line that starts with “linux”, and use the right arrow key to find the section with the words “ro quiet splash”.
4. Add “nomodeset” after these words.

   nomodeset
5. Feel free to remove “quiet” and “splash” for more verbosity to troubleshoot the boot process.
6. Press “CTRL + X” or “F10” to boot.
7. The system should now boot

For permanent [fix](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.stephenwagner.com/2019/05/05/ubuntu-linux-black-screen-frozen-system-after-upgrade-install/amp/)

Comment: So I just repaired in grub and then rebooted it, seems to work fine now, thanks.